# Unable refresh ListView in my android app

Tags: android, listview

I'm very new to android development. I'm trying to implement search functionality in my app & retrieving data from DB and showing it in list view. When I'm doing next search, the results are added to list view rather than being refreshed. Please look at my code and suggest a possible solution.

```
    public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    ListView lv;
    EditText etSearch;
    ImageButton ibSearch;

    InputStream is = null;
    String line = null;
    String result = null;
    String temp = "";
    String[] arr = null;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lv);
        etSearch = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etSearch);
        ibSearch = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.ibSearch);

        ibSearch.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                String input = etSearch.getText().toString();
                retrieveData(input);
            }
        });
    }

    public void retrieveData(String input){
        StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
        StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);

        ArrayList<NameValuePair> dataToSend = new ArrayList<>();
        dataToSend.add(new BasicNameValuePair("input", input));

        try {
            HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost("http://www.coderstop.net/android/display.php");
            httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(dataToSend));
            HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
            HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();

            is = entity.getContent();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("1st Exception caught");
        }

        try {
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line + "\n");
            }

            result = sb.toString();
            is.close();

            System.out.println("----------data------------");
            System.out.println(result);


        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("2nd Exception caught");
        }


        try {
            JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(result);
            int count = jsonArray.length();

            for(int i=0;i<count;i++){
                JSONObject jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                temp += jsonObject.getString("NAME").trim()+":";
            }
            //count = 0;
            arr = null;
            System.out.println(temp);
            arr = temp.split(":");

            ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(MainActivity.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, arr);
            lv.setAdapter(adapter);
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("3rd Exception caught");
        }

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

Comment: well if you want to show your new results u need to clear your previous results (i.e clear your list first and then add the results.)

Comment: First time when data load then it goes into `lv.setAdapter(adapter);` but when next time you search then it should not be call setAdapter() method then it should only call `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();` method. So, do code like that way.

Comment: Don't write code to work with Http and parse Json! Use Gson, Volley/Okhttp and other third-party libraries.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here in this for loop you are assigning value to temp.

```
for(int i=0;i<count;i++){
        JSONObject jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
        temp += jsonObject.getString("NAME").trim()+":";
    }
```

but you never set the value of temp to null or blank string (""). So when you are searching again the new result is added to the list of previous result.

The solution is you need to set use temp = ""; before for loop.

Hope this helps you :)
If you have any problem please let me know 
Thanks :)

Comment: Thanks a lot! It was very silly of me and I was trying like more than 3 hrs.